# Clang + OpenMP inefficient loop invariants

Tags: c++, optimization, clang, openmp

I came across some inefficient code generation by Clang while answering a different question ([How do i parallelize this code using openmp with reduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71275315/how-do-i-parallelize-this-code-using-openmp-with-reduction/71276124#71276124))

Let's consider this simple code:

```
void scale(float* inout, ptrdiff_t n, ptrdiff_t m, ptrdiff_t stride, float value)
{
    const float inverse = 1.f / value;
#   pragma omp parallel for
    for(ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
#       pragma omp simd
        for(ptrdiff_t j = 0; j < m; ++j)
            inout[i * stride + j] *= inverse;
    }
}
```

Where do you put the computation of the inverse and does it matter? Options that I've explored:

1. Outside the loop, where it is in the example
2. In the parallel section but before the loop
3. In the outer loop
4. in the inner loop

For GCC-11, option 1 generates the best code: One division, then a single memory load and broadcast per thread. Option 2-4 all generate basically the same code, doing the division once per thread.

### Clang assembly

However, with Clang-13 the code is vastly different.

Option 1: Does a redundant memory load and broadcast *in the inner loop*. And it doesn't load via stack pointer but wastes a general purpose register as a pointer to the constant. If you change the code to require multiple constants, Clang will waste multiple GP registers.

Option 2: Same code pattern as GCC

Option 3: Repeats the division once per iteration of the outer loop

Option 4: Repeats the division in the inner loop

### Summary

It seems as if Clang's code generation has some issues with pulling redundant computations out of OpenMP loops. Interestingly, it doesn't seem to affect the array index computation. That gets pulled out of the inner loop just fine.

If I want code that works well on both GCC and Clang, I have to write something like this:

```
void scale(float* inout, ptrdiff_t n, ptrdiff_t m, ptrdiff_t stride, float value)
{
#   pragma omp parallel
    {
        const float inverse = 1.f / value;
#       pragma omp for nowait
        for(ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
#           pragma omp simd
            for(ptrdiff_t j = 0; j < m; ++j)
                inout[i * stride + j] *= inverse;
        }
    }
}
```

But that is awfully verbose.
This whole thing is a minor nuisance in this code example but if you check out the code in the other answer above, it gets so bad (especially with the GP register waste) that it seriously impacts performance.

So in conclusion, am I missing something? Should I write loops differently to ensure good code in both Clang and GCC?

### Supplementary information

Here is a version of the code that allows easy testing and here is a [Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYgATKVpMGoZAFI9AIQuXSS%2BsgJ4BlRugDCqWgFcWDfdJuADJ4DJgAcr4ARpjEEgDspAAOqAqEzgyePn4ByanpAiFhkSwxcVyJ9piOGUIETMQEWb7%2BetJVNQJ1DQRFEdGxCXb1jc05bcM9fSVlCQCUdqjexMjsHBYAzKHIPlgA1GYb7sgKBOhYVIfYZhoAggD093veaSZ7p%2BggIEkExPhUVAA%2BgQbrdQZsLqFMHt3AB5cJCAAqgKCsPct0RAEl4XsuOC7gA3VB4dDvUT0ai0VBMAgAKj2oSWBFI7zOXx%2BfzwAOBewYLI%2B7N%2B/yBBD2LH5bO%2BQq5ItZxBJmFIoL2KtVar2VCpNL2BLE3kwc3B8Wsd02DKoMPhSJRaIx2PCBw2ABFDk7ccrVfdaR7VfT3EYTABaLgbAB0GlDXBAewASph0N4GOhjKKosRqehRKcNemWGLMCwSABPBkMUthYh7KmoJKhn0q%2BnqpuqgDqTFOmAUewA4so9sRMMA8B3K/xKylQgRYnsiHs0AxTin63t6d33O5g1xQ3po7CfngWGJl7T7vX59nNdTRaECY63VuLU9dT5MIcTbcVZs3FzwXoNqqkmIJhgEPPZUBYJI9iSBoxHoWh6zMY1f3/NUuUtBFkVRdEsRxV1XT2PRl09b07mbBsYQDUBY3jRNk0EOdwKSbx6icARSzA5jp2rSClAIbxaz2WECAQWIAHdh2hGsnEPeDSLI1d12jIRWGhdsKOMYAiN9U85Kbc9RUvbUbzvXFQ0fHU9VfDZ3zNNVv0uU0/2bQDgNAxiNRIXlUFEphCC0jziAgAUpU5blrxMjQ3wZR13F5KKbBsPA5gOJDHJQ5s0LhDCbWw%2B073wjZ/LVL0irVP1KOjOMEyTFMGIg5iaQydjQgrKtUBrd5MD4pIwDAUrfR7RS9mUtg9jUwjdLIhsdI/KaVX0jUtWvBhb3wh89ifSy32Qqb7J2uaXJApgwIg94D3QfqAqCyUOWFHltAiqKHsOWKWHiqwbG0ZLEJspy5pVTKrUw20cIdPDnT2SRLuKkjZv%2Bsr1JMSqaJq%2Bi0HqlimtCcsuPanq%2Bsm%2BGV0G9wlJUsauwmuGiZXGaafmgQLyW0tVoh9bNpfba0qJvbCf%2BxlmLMABWSw8FpU55X2Gw9m0YW3W9CGby56myMQl0%2Bc/eJ1eptWjSdDgFloTghd4fwOC0UhUE4dwEqsd4lhWaFNj0XgCE0A2FhEpgsDiCAFgAaxASQhcjPQhYANnDvR4kkAAOWONmDrhDE4SReBYEAhY0UgzYtq2OF4BQQGzt3zYN0g4FgJB0aSOhYnISga7ruIdg0kMNGTmhaCnYgi4gKJ3dIKJQgaItOB4Uh0bYQRYQYWgx7L0gsEPExxEX/ABxqAlO0HzBVGqTjx94SdMCNxfaDwNNR88LBB9%2BA8j4WTVgIUAA1PBMFEvdGCPmRBBEMQ7ApB/3kEoNQg9dAGAquYD6VhDCXyLpABYUkMhFw4IGWE/5Az8CSIwU6gZDwElUHoPYBCqCHkLqfaorF/AQDcGMfwydghQhmIMZOKQ0g0IYRIPInCMjTAGOUOwVDOgMG6KMLwLQeEdBoeI3oLDBHSJGE0SRORk6LkaAI0obCFgKAdqsfQpBfiYDWDwQ2xtTaD3zqoWO4dAzh0kHOSiuIwwRi4HsCANtYG2D2LgQgnlnYsk8BBZuBw/x6DmK7d2cxPaYG9oMP2pBA4bDDJHLgGg9CZK4HoWO8Q8kaGkGfNOOcrGcELsXIx0SK4wEQCAJkTFmQUAgE3egcQDDxn8W0kBADxDAP4IIRQKh1CL1EkBJIj8U4cBNiUxe%2BdYTMQaWBC0Ni7EOKcRpFx4ZIweOCbXVpYSNgRKiWXGJST9Bbj0CGDYXAs4bFjjkvJiQimWNmWUuwFTS5aFOWfF2pAM7pOzrnXg%2BdjlfIWNvXuGQg5AA)

```
#include <cstddef>
// using std::ptrdiff_t

#define CONST_LOCATION 1

void scale(float* inout, std::ptrdiff_t n, std::ptrdiff_t m, std::ptrdiff_t stride,
           float value)
{
# if CONST_LOCATION == 1
    /*
     * Clang-13.0.1: Redundant broadcast from memory in inner loop.
     *               Wastes GP register for pointer to constant
     * GCC-11.2: Optimal
     */
    const float inv = 1.f / value;
  #endif
#   pragma omp parallel
    {
#     if CONST_LOCATION == 2
        /*
         * Clang: Redundant computation in outer loop setup. Otherwise optimal
         * GCC: Same as Clang
         */
        const float inv = 1.f / value;
#     endif
#       pragma omp for nowait
        for(std::ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
#         if CONST_LOCATION == 3
            /*
             * Clang: Redundant computation in inner loop setup!
             * GCC: Same as 2
             */
            const float inv = 1.f / value;
#         endif
#           pragma omp simd
            for(std::ptrdiff_t j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
#             if CONST_LOCATION == 4
                /*
                 * Clang: Redundant computation in inner loop!
                 * GCC: Same as 2
                 */
                const float inv = 1.f / value;
#             endif
                inout[i*stride + j] *= inv;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tested with `-O3 -mavx2 -mfma -fopenmp` for a reasonably generic, modern compilation.

Comment: Did you try to have inverse as a 8-element constant array declared in innermost loop and have its element acces as modulus of loop counter? This way, omp doesnt have to broadcast scalar value, I guess.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I remember seeing some assembly where the compiler spilled a whole vector on stack and reloaded it in the inner loop. That is something like what you suggest. However, I'm more interested in a natural looking code pattern. I mean, this whole thing really shouldn't be complicated, right? It's a very simple loop

Comment: I 've seen simpler loops that were not parallelized in msvc++ omp

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik MSVC actually produces reasonable code https://godbolt.org/z/vET4oob4x … MSVC beating Clang. You don't see that every day

Comment: What are your optimization settings? That makes a big difference.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout ```-O3 -mavx2 -mfma``` as in the Godbolt link. I will add a note to the question

Comment: I know that you're asking about that inverse, but I wonder about the interaction between `AVX2` and `simd`. I've found that most compilers (well, the Intel one that I use by default, at least.) can discover most SIMD cases by themselves. Just for fun, on the assumption that `omp simd` throws off the compiler, what kind of results do you get if you leave the SIMD stuff to the compiler?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Aww, crap, you are right. It's the simd statement. I thought I checked without but I must have messed something up. Without it, clang produces reasonable code.

Answer (score 1):

To answer myself, it's the `pragma omp simd` in the inner loop that messes up clang's code generation. Which is a shame because it does have a positive effect in some cases on some compilers.

Comment: I've been impressed with how well compilers can figure out simd for themselves, including limited length dependencies `x[i] = x[i-25]` and that sort of thing. I think OpenMP simd is mostly useful if you want to simd'ize over functions. Compilers have a much harder time with that.