# Write numpy einsum operation as eigen tensors

Tags: c++, eigen, matrix-multiplication, tensor, numpy-einsum

I want to write the following numpy einsum as a an Eigen Tensor op

```py
import numpy as np

L = np.random.rand(2, 2, 136)
U = np.random.rand(2, 2, 136)

result = np.einsum('ijl,jkl->ikl', U, L)
```

I can write it with for loops like so in C++

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < 136; l++) {
          result(i, k, l) += U(i, j, l) * L(j, k, l);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

How do I write in eigen notation using its operations? Using for loops doesn't allow eigen to properly vectorize the operations, as I have complicated scalar types.

Edit.

As asked for, a Jet is an extension of dual numbers, where each element is a number, followed by an array of gradients of that number wrt some parameters.
http://ceres-solver.org/automatic_derivatives.html

A naive implmentation might look like

```
template<typename T, int N>
struct Jet
{
    T a;
    T v[N];
};
```

If the jet is written using eigen ops, the idea is that using expression templates, eigen should vectorize all operations directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no contraction happening in the 3rd dimension "`l`" in your case. So, in a sense, `L` and `U` are arrays of length 136 of 2x2 matrices, and you are multiplying the matrix `U[l]` with `L[l]`. I think doing something similar to [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) with Eigen is therefore not possible; [`Eigen::Tensor::contract`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/eigen_tensors.html#title56) only supports "real" contractions. But one can of course always do the loop over the 3rd dimension manually. But as shown below, this performs very badly.

Nevertheless, there are ways to speed things up and vectorize the loops, by either relying on automatic vectorization (did not work well for me) or by giving additional compiler hints (via OpenMP SIMD).

In the following, I define `cDim12=2` as the size of the first and second dimension, and `cDim13=136` as the third dimension.
For the timings, all code was compiled with `-O3 -mavx` with gcc 11.2 and clang 15.0.2. I used [google benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark) to get the timings on an Intel Core i7-4770K (yeah, quite a few years old, sorry). Eigen trunk (08c961e83) from 20th January 2023 was used.

**TL;DR:** To summarize the results below:

- Using the manual loop (with better iteration order), auto-vectorization via an OpenMP-SIMD pragma and also raw access with **gcc** was the fastest ("DirectAccessWithOMP"): 2.8x faster than your straightforward loop with AVX. I guess this comes close to being "optimal" (cf. [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9qovMKbTe)).
- I couldn't get clang to vectorize the loop properly. Since you mentioned that either gcc or clang is fine, you seem to have the choice and I'd stick with gcc.
- Python appears to be an order of magnitude or more slower compared to the fastest gcc result.

**Note:** Measure your real world application, since things might behave completely different there!

### Code from the original post as baseline ("FromOriginalPost")

The straightforward code from your original post looks like this and is used as baseline.

```
Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> result(cDim12, cDim12, cDim3);
result.setZero();
for (int i = 0; i < cDim12; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < cDim12; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < cDim12; k++) {
      for (int l = 0; l < cDim3; l++) {
        result(i, k, l) += U(i, j, l) * L(j, k, l);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Optimized loop order ("OptimizedOrder")

Note that `Eigen::Tensor` uses [column major order](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/eigen_tensors.html#title5) by default (and row major is not recommended). Thus, in an expression such as `U(i, j, l)`, the `i` should be the fastest (most inner) loop and `l` the slowest (most outer) loop. Reordering as best as I could:

```
for (int l = 0; l < cDim3; l++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < cDim12; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < cDim12; k++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < cDim12; i++) {
        result(i, k, l) += U(i, j, l) * L(j, k, l);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is 1.3x-1.4x faster.

### Using `Eigen::Tensor::chip` and `contract` ("EigenChipAndContract")

Using Eigen features as much as possible, I came up with the following:

```
Eigen::array<Eigen::IndexPair<int>, 1> productDims = {Eigen::IndexPair<int>(1, 0)};
Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> result(cDim12, cDim12, cDim3);
for (int l = 0; l < cDim3; l++) {
  result.chip(l, 2) = U.chip(l, 2).contract(L.chip(l, 2), productDims);
}
```

This performs very bad: It is 18x slower on gcc and 24x slower on clang when compared to "FromOriginalPost".

### Using `Eigen::TensorMap` and `contract` ("EigenMapAndContract")

The "EigenChipAndContract" might do a lot of copying, so another idea was to use `Eigen::TensorMap` to get "references" to each necessary "slice" of data. For the raw array access, note again that Eigen uses column-major order.

```
Eigen::array<Eigen::IndexPair<int>, 1> productDims = {Eigen::IndexPair<int>(1, 0)};
Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> result(cDim12, cDim12, cDim3);
for (int l = 0; l < cDim3; l++) {
  Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<double, 2>> U_chip(U.data() + l * cDim12 * cDim12, cDim12, cDim12);
  Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<double, 2>> L_chip(L.data() + l * cDim12 * cDim12, cDim12, cDim12);
  Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<double, 2>> result_chip(result.data() + l * cDim12 * cDim12, cDim12, cDim12);
  result_chip = U_chip.contract(L_chip, productDims);
}
```

This is actually somewhat faster than "EigenChipAndContract", but still very slow. Compared to "FromOriginalPost", this is 14x slower for gcc and 19x slower for clang.

### Vectorization with OpenMP ("EigenAccessWithOMP")

Although both [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html) and [clang](https://llvm.org/docs/Vectorizers.html) can do automatic vectorization, without additional hints they do not yield good results. However, both support the OpenMP pragma [`#pragma omp simd collapse(4)`](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu42.html), when compiled with `-fopenmp`:

```
#pragma omp simd collapse(4)
for (int l = 0; l < cDim3; l++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < cDim12; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < cDim12; k++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < cDim12; i++) {
        result(i, k, l) += U(i, j, l) * L(j, k, l);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Compilation with `-O3 -mavx -fopenmp` results in

- a 2.5x **faster** runtime compared to the original code ("FromOriginalPost") for gcc,
- but for clang, however, the code is 2.5x **slower**. Searching for clang + OpenMP-SIMD issues, apparently clang does have troubles sometimes (e.g. in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71294894/3740047) post).
  Checking the result on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/hbK167rYq), clang indeed produces quite lengthy results.

### Vectorization with OpenMP + direct raw access ("DirectAccessWithOMP")

The previous code used the `Eigen::Tensor::operator()`, which should inline to the raw array accesses. However, remembering the column-major layout, we can also access the underlying array directly and check whether this improves anything. It also allows to give the hint to the compiler again that the data is properly aligned (although Eigen already defines them as such).

```
double * pR = result.data();
double * pU = U.data();
double * pL = L.data();

#pragma omp simd collapse(4) aligned(pR, pU, pL: 32) // 32: For AVX
for (int l = 0; l < cDim3; l++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < cDim12; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < cDim12; k++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < cDim12; i++) {
        pR[i + cDim12*(k + cDim12*l)] += pU[i + cDim12*(j + cDim12*l)] * pL[j + cDim12*(k + cDim12*l)];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Somewhat surprisingly, this is 1.1x faster for gcc and 1.4x faster for clang when compared with "EigenAccessWithOMP".
When compared with the original "FromOriginalPost", it is 2.8x faster for gcc and 2.5x slower for clang.

When viewed on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jnTTG3hrc), gcc really produces some quite concise assembly.

### Python

Not sure how far fetched it is to compare the absolute execution time of a call to `np.einsum` with the C++ version, since Python needs to do additional string parsing etc. Nevertheless, here is the code:

```py
import numpy as np
import timeit

L = np.random.rand(2, 2, 136)
U = np.random.rand(2, 2, 136)

numIterations = 1000000
timing = timeit.timeit(lambda: np.einsum('ijl,jkl->ikl', U, L), number=numIterations)
print(f"np.einsum (per iteration): {timing.real/(numIterations*1e-9)}ns")
```

For Python 3.9 and numpy-1.24.1 this is roughly 6x times slower compared to "FromOriginalPost" and 16x times slower compared to "DirectAccessWithOMP" for gcc.

## Raw timings

For gcc:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                     Time             CPU   Iterations
---------------------------------------------------------------
FromOriginalPost            823 ns          823 ns      3397793
OptimizedOrder              573 ns          573 ns      4895246
DirectAccess               1306 ns         1306 ns      2142826
EigenAccessWithOMP          324 ns          324 ns      8655549
DirectAccessWithOMP         296 ns          296 ns      9418635
EigenChipAndContract      14405 ns        14405 ns       193548
EigenMapAndContract       11390 ns        11390 ns       243122
```

For clang:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                     Time             CPU   Iterations
---------------------------------------------------------------
FromOriginalPost            753 ns          753 ns      3714543
OptimizedOrder              570 ns          570 ns      4921914
DirectAccess                569 ns          569 ns      4929755
EigenAccessWithOMP         2704 ns         2704 ns      1037819
DirectAccessWithOMP        1908 ns         1908 ns      1466390
EigenChipAndContract      17713 ns        17713 ns       157427
EigenMapAndContract       14064 ns        14064 ns       198875
```

Python:

```
np.einsum (per iteration): 4873.6035999991145 ns
```

## Full code

Also on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/aGY5YMPGr), however not really useful since the compiler times out there quite often.
Locally I compiled with `-O3 -DNDEBUG -std=c++17 -mavx  -fopenmp -Wall -Wextra`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

//====================================================
// Globals
//====================================================

static constexpr int cDim12 = 2;
static constexpr int cDim3 = 136;


Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> CreateRandomTensor()
{
  Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> m(cDim12, cDim12, cDim3);
  m.setRandom();
  return m;
}


Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> const L = CreateRandomTensor();
Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> const U = CreateRandomTensor();


//====================================================
// Helpers
//====================================================

Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> ReferenceResult() 
{
  Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> result(cDim12, cDim12, cDim3);
  result.setZero();
  for (int i = 0; i < cDim12; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cDim12; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < cDim12; k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < cDim3; l++) {
          result(i, k, l) += U(i, j, l) * L(j, k, l);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}



void CheckResult(Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> const & result) 
{
  Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> const ref = ReferenceResult();
  Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> const diff = ref - result;
  Eigen::Tensor<double, 0> const max = diff.maximum();
  Eigen::Tensor<double, 0> const min = diff.minimum();
  double const maxDiff = std::max(std::abs(max(0)), std::abs(min(0)));
  if (maxDiff > 1e-14) {
    std::cerr << "ERROR! Max Diff = " << std::setprecision(17) << maxDiff << std::endl;
  }
}


//====================================================
// Benchmarks
//====================================================


static void FromOriginalPost(benchmark::State& state) 
{
  Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> result(cDim12, cDim12, cDim3);
  for (auto _ : state) {
    result.setZero();
    for (int i = 0; i < cDim12; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < cDim12; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < cDim12; k++) {
          for (int l = 0; l < cDim3; l++) {
            result(i, k, l) += U(i, j, l) * L(j, k, l);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(result.data());
  }

  CheckResult(result);
}
BENCHMARK(FromOriginalPost);


static void OptimizedOrder(benchmark::State& state) 
{
  Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> result(cDim12, cDim12, cDim3);
  for (auto _ : state) {
    result.setZero();
    for (int l = 0; l < cDim3; l++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < cDim12; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < cDim12; k++) {
          for (int i = 0; i < cDim12; i++) {
            result(i, k, l) += U(i, j, l) * L(j, k, l);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(result.data());
  }

  CheckResult(result);
}
BENCHMARK(OptimizedOrder);


static void DirectAccess(benchmark::State& state) 
{
  Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> U = ::U;
  Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> L = ::L;

  Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> result(cDim12, cDim12, cDim3);
  for (auto _ : state) {
    result.setZero();
    double * pR = result.data();
    double * pU = U.data();
    double * pL = L.data();

    for (int l = 0; l < cDim3; l++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < cDim12; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < cDim12; k++) {
          for (int i = 0; i < cDim12; i++) {
            pR[i + cDim12*(k + cDim12*l)] += pU[i + cDim12*(j + cDim12*l)] * pL[j + cDim12*(k + cDim12*l)];
          }
        }
      }
    }

    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(result.data());
  }

  CheckResult(result);
}
BENCHMARK(DirectAccess);


static void EigenAccessWithOMP(benchmark::State& state) 
{
  Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> result(cDim12, cDim12, cDim3);
  for (auto _ : state) {
    result.setZero();
    #pragma omp simd collapse(4)
    for (int l = 0; l < cDim3; l++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < cDim12; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < cDim12; k++) {
          for (int i = 0; i < cDim12; i++) {
            result(i, k, l) += U(i, j, l) * L(j, k, l);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(result.data());
  }

  CheckResult(result);
}
BENCHMARK(EigenAccessWithOMP);


static void DirectAccessWithOMP(benchmark::State& state) 
{
  Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> U = ::U;
  Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> L = ::L;

  Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> result(cDim12, cDim12, cDim3);
  for (auto _ : state) {
    result.setZero();
    double * pR = result.data();
    double * pU = U.data();
    double * pL = L.data();

    #pragma omp simd collapse(4) aligned(pR, pU, pL: 32) // 32: For AVX
    for (int l = 0; l < cDim3; l++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < cDim12; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < cDim12; k++) {
          for (int i = 0; i < cDim12; i++) {
            pR[i + cDim12*(k + cDim12*l)] += pU[i + cDim12*(j + cDim12*l)] * pL[j + cDim12*(k + cDim12*l)];
          }
        }
      }
    }

    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(result.data());
  }

  CheckResult(result);
}
BENCHMARK(DirectAccessWithOMP);


static void EigenChipAndContract(benchmark::State& state) 
{
  Eigen::array<Eigen::IndexPair<int>, 1> productDims = {Eigen::IndexPair<int>(1, 0)};
  Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> result(cDim12, cDim12, cDim3);
  for (auto _ : state) {
    result.setZero();
    for (int l = 0; l < cDim3; l++) {
      result.chip(l, 2) = U.chip(l, 2).contract(L.chip(l, 2), productDims);
    }
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(result.data());
  }

  CheckResult(result);
}
BENCHMARK(EigenChipAndContract);


static void EigenMapAndContract(benchmark::State& state) 
{
  Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> U = ::U;
  Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> L = ::L;
  Eigen::array<Eigen::IndexPair<int>, 1> productDims = {Eigen::IndexPair<int>(1, 0)};

  Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> result(cDim12, cDim12, cDim3);
  for (auto _ : state) {
    result.setZero();
    for (int l = 0; l < cDim3; l++) {
      Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<double, 2>> U_chip(U.data() + l * cDim12 * cDim12, cDim12, cDim12);
      Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<double, 2>> L_chip(L.data() + l * cDim12 * cDim12, cDim12, cDim12);
      Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<double, 2>> result_chip(result.data() + l * cDim12 * cDim12, cDim12, cDim12);
      result_chip = U_chip.contract(L_chip, productDims);
    }
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(result.data());
  }

  CheckResult(result);
}
BENCHMARK(EigenMapAndContract);


BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

---

---

## EDIT for jets

After the original post was edited, the arithmetic types used are not really built-ins but rather [jets](http://ceres-solver.org/automatic_derivatives.html#dual-numbers-jets). Eigen can be extended to support custom types (as briefly outlined [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_CustomScalar.html)). However, the `Eigen::Tensor::contract()` function nevertheless does not "magically" support the equivalent of `np.einsum('ijl,jkl->ikl', U, L)` since the last dimension `l` does not really perform a contraction. Of course, one could write one, but this seems far from trivial.

If the only required contraction-like operation is the one from the original post, and also the tensors are not further multiplied/added/etc, the simplest thing to do is to implement the single loop manually and play around with compilers, compiler settings, pragmas, etc to figure out the best performance.

Jet type (adapted from [here](http://ceres-solver.org/automatic_derivatives.html#dual-numbers-jets)):

```
template<int N> struct Jet {
  double a = 0.0;
  Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, N> v = Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, N>::Zero();
};

template<int N> 
EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Jet<N> operator+(const Jet<N>& f, const Jet<N>& g) {
  return Jet<N>{f.a + g.a, f.v + g.v};
}

template<int N> 
EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Jet<N> operator*(const Jet<N>& f, const Jet<N>& g) {
  return Jet<N>{f.a * g.a, f.a * g.v + f.v * g.a};
}
```

For example (column-major)

```
Eigen::Tensor<Jet<N>, 3> L = CreateRandomTensor<Eigen::ColMajor>();
Eigen::Tensor<Jet<N>, 3> U = CreateRandomTensor<Eigen::ColMajor>();

Eigen::Tensor<Jet<N>, 3> result(cDim12, cDim12, cDim3);
SetToZero(result);

for (int l = 0; l < cDim3; l++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < cDim12; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < cDim12; k++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < cDim12; i++) {
        Jet<N> & r = result(i, k, l);
        r = r + U(i, j, l) * L(j, k, l);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or with row-major order:

```
Eigen::Tensor<Jet<N>, 3, Eigen::RowMajor> L = CreateRandomTensor<Eigen::RowMajor>();
Eigen::Tensor<Jet<N>, 3, Eigen::RowMajor> U = CreateRandomTensor<Eigen::RowMajor>();

Eigen::Tensor<Jet<N>, 3, Eigen::RowMajor> result(cDim12, cDim12, cDim3);
SetToZero(result);

for (int i = 0; i < cDim12; i++) {
  for (int k = 0; k < cDim12; k++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cDim12; j++) {
      for (int l = 0; l < cDim3; l++) {
        Jet<N> & r = result(i, k, l);
        r = r + U(i, j, l) * L(j, k, l);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

gcc and clang yield the same performance. They [auto-vectorize the column-major loops](https://godbolt.org/z/GM11ec3s1), but apparently not the row-major ones. Direct access of the underlying data does not improve things. Moreover, adding `#pragma omp simd collapse(4)` results in worse performance in both cases (clang also warns that the loops could not be vectorized); I guess the explicit SIMDs used in the matrix multiplication of `Jet::v` internally by Eigen are the reason.

As an additional note again: The [Eigen documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/eigen_tensors.html#title5) says that you shouldn't really combine row-major order with `Eigen::Tensor`:

> The tensor library supports 2 layouts: ColMajor (the default) and RowMajor. Only the default column major layout is currently fully supported, and it is therefore not recommended to attempt to use the row major layout at the moment.

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>


static constexpr int cDim12 = 2;
static constexpr int cDim3 = 136;


template<int N> struct Jet {
  double a = 0.0;
  Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, N> v = Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, N>::Zero();
};

template<int N> 
EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Jet<N> operator+(const Jet<N>& f, const Jet<N>& g) {
  return Jet<N>{f.a + g.a, f.v + g.v};
}

template<int N> 
EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Jet<N> operator-(const Jet<N>& f, const Jet<N>& g) {
  return Jet<N>{f.a - g.a, f.v - g.v};
}

template<int N> 
EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Jet<N> operator*(const Jet<N>& f, const Jet<N>& g) {
  return Jet<N>{f.a * g.a, f.a * g.v + f.v * g.a};
}

template<int N> 
EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Jet<N> operator/(const Jet<N>& f, const Jet<N>& g) {
  return Jet<N>{f.a / g.a, f.v / g.a - f.a * g.v / (g.a * g.a)};
}



static constexpr int N = 8;


template <Eigen::StorageOptions storage>
auto CreateRandomTensor()
{
  Eigen::Tensor<Jet<N>, 3, storage> result(cDim12, cDim12, cDim3);
  for (int l = 0; l < cDim3; l++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < cDim12; k++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < cDim12; i++) {
        Jet<N> jet;
        jet.a = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
        jet.v.setRandom();
        result(i, k, l) = jet;
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}


template <class T>
void SetToZero(T & result)
{
  for (int l = 0; l < cDim3; l++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < cDim12; k++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < cDim12; i++) {
        result(i, k, l) = Jet<N>{};
      }
    }
  }
}


static void EigenAccessNoOMP(benchmark::State& state) 
{
  srand(42);
  Eigen::Tensor<Jet<N>, 3> L = CreateRandomTensor<Eigen::ColMajor>();
  Eigen::Tensor<Jet<N>, 3> U = CreateRandomTensor<Eigen::ColMajor>();

  Eigen::Tensor<Jet<N>, 3> result(cDim12, cDim12, cDim3);
  for (auto _ : state) {
    SetToZero(result);

    for (int l = 0; l < cDim3; l++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < cDim12; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < cDim12; k++) {
          for (int i = 0; i < cDim12; i++) {
            Jet<N> & r = result(i, k, l);
            r = r + U(i, j, l) * L(j, k, l);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(result.data());
  }
}
BENCHMARK(EigenAccessNoOMP);


static void EigenAccessNoOMPRowMajor(benchmark::State& state) 
{
  srand(42);
  Eigen::Tensor<Jet<N>, 3, Eigen::RowMajor> L = CreateRandomTensor<Eigen::RowMajor>();
  Eigen::Tensor<Jet<N>, 3, Eigen::RowMajor> U = CreateRandomTensor<Eigen::RowMajor>();

  Eigen::Tensor<Jet<N>, 3, Eigen::RowMajor> result(cDim12, cDim12, cDim3);
  for (auto _ : state) {
    SetToZero(result);

    for (int i = 0; i < cDim12; i++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < cDim12; k++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cDim12; j++) {
          for (int l = 0; l < cDim3; l++) {
            Jet<N> & r = result(i, k, l);
            r = r + U(i, j, l) * L(j, k, l);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(result.data());
  }
}
BENCHMARK(EigenAccessNoOMPRowMajor);



static void DirectAccessNoOMP(benchmark::State& state) 
{
  srand(42);
  Eigen::Tensor<Jet<N>, 3> L = CreateRandomTensor<Eigen::ColMajor>();
  Eigen::Tensor<Jet<N>, 3> U = CreateRandomTensor<Eigen::ColMajor>();

  Eigen::Tensor<Jet<N>, 3> result(cDim12, cDim12, cDim3);
  for (auto _ : state) {
    SetToZero(result);

    Jet<N> * pR = result.data();
    Jet<N> * pU = U.data();
    Jet<N> * pL = L.data();

    for (int l = 0; l < cDim3; l++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < cDim12; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < cDim12; k++) {
          for (int i = 0; i < cDim12; i++) {
            Jet<N> & r = pR[i + cDim12*(k + cDim12*l)];
            r = r + pU[i + cDim12*(j + cDim12*l)] * pL[j + cDim12*(k + cDim12*l)];
          }
        }
      }
    }

    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(result.data());
  }
}
BENCHMARK(DirectAccessNoOMP);


static void EigenAccessWithOMP(benchmark::State& state) 
{
  srand(42);
  Eigen::Tensor<Jet<N>, 3> L = CreateRandomTensor<Eigen::ColMajor>();
  Eigen::Tensor<Jet<N>, 3> U = CreateRandomTensor<Eigen::ColMajor>();

  Eigen::Tensor<Jet<N>, 3> result(cDim12, cDim12, cDim3);
  for (auto _ : state) {
    SetToZero(result);

    #pragma omp simd collapse(4)
    for (int l = 0; l < cDim3; l++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < cDim12; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < cDim12; k++) {
          for (int i = 0; i < cDim12; i++) {
            Jet<N> & r = result(i, k, l);
            r = r + U(i, j, l) * L(j, k, l);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(result.data());
  }
}
BENCHMARK(EigenAccessWithOMP);



static void DirectAccessWithOMP(benchmark::State& state) 
{
  srand(42);
  Eigen::Tensor<Jet<N>, 3> L = CreateRandomTensor<Eigen::ColMajor>();
  Eigen::Tensor<Jet<N>, 3> U = CreateRandomTensor<Eigen::ColMajor>();

  Eigen::Tensor<Jet<N>, 3> result(cDim12, cDim12, cDim3);
  for (auto _ : state) {
    SetToZero(result);

    Jet<N> * pR = result.data();
    Jet<N> * pU = U.data();
    Jet<N> * pL = L.data();

    #pragma omp simd collapse(4) aligned(pR, pU, pL: 32)
    for (int l = 0; l < cDim3; l++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < cDim12; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < cDim12; k++) {
          for (int i = 0; i < cDim12; i++) {
            Jet<N> & r = pR[i + cDim12*(k + cDim12*l)];
            r = r + pU[i + cDim12*(j + cDim12*l)] * pL[j + cDim12*(k + cDim12*l)];
          }
        }
      }
    }

    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(result.data());
  }
}
BENCHMARK(DirectAccessWithOMP);



BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

Comment: So don't use clang?

Comment: @MadPhysicist In this **very** specific case, I'd say yes: use gcc instead of clang. gcc performs much better here. But it really depends on the application. I also had other (completely unrelated) code where clang was better than gcc at optimizing it.

Comment: My row order was already optimized for RowMajor as the data is created from a previous operation that is designed for row major arrays. The reason I want to use eigen expressions is that my data-type is not arithmetic types but jets and so simd optimizations like this don't apply. I had hoped to use eigen's expressions to auto optimize the operation.

Comment: @NiteyaShah I don't understand: Eigen can only use vectorization on built in arithmetic types. If you use some other types, say some struct unknown to Eigen, how do you expect Eigen to vectorize this? Also, your numpy code is using floating points. And what do you mean by "jet"? So please update your question and explain what you actually have and want. It seems you are not really after vectorization (i.e. use of SIMDs)?

Comment: Eigen should be able to operate on other types as well, as long as define them using expression templates and implement the information eigen needs to operate on them as regular types. I have updated my question to include information of jets.

Comment: @NiteyaShah I didn't think you were willing to go as far as extending Eigen to custom types. However, `Eigen::Tensor::contract` still does not magically support the `'ijl,jkl->ikl'` operation. So you need to implement it yourself anyway. Or, if this is the only operation of Eigen you actually need, it is still easier to implement it via loops and play with compilers and settings, etc. gcc and clang do vectorize the loops. I amended my answer with an example. Or are you doing many more things with the tensors, so that extending Eigen is actually worth the effort?

Comment: I have no issues with designing an optimal method for this using simple for loops. I can even unroll the inner loop of Jets and perform optimal SIMD operations. Unfortunately, this defeats the purpose of using eigen in the first place. I have to support multiple architectures(x86-64, arm, nvidia and amd) and eigen should allow for the lowest translation effort between them.

 I have no problems with extending eigen expressions to support this method as we will have similar future problems come up that we need to support.

Comment: @NiteyaShah Ok. But what do you expect as answer on stackoverflow then? A ready-to-use extension of Eigen to jets and additionally a generalization of `Eigen::Tensor::contract`? I doubt that anyone is willing to do this work for you. Or is the answer to your original question simply "there is nothing like `np.einsum('ijl,jkl->ikl', U, L)` in Eigen"?

Comment: @Sedenion I don't need the extension of eigen to utilize jets. As the question asks, I want an implementation of a function that uses eigen expressions (and not for loops) to generate optimal code for this einsum. If you can create a function using eigen expressions for even ordinary data types(doubles or floats) that is properly vectorized, I can work with that. As you saw in your implementation using chips, this doesn't work well. I don't want hand optimized for loops.

Comment: @NiteyaShah The only other idea I have is to view your tensor as a `2*136 x 2*136` sparse matrix: For each `l` in `U(i,j,l)`, the `i,j` forms a 2x2 matrix. Put those on the diagonal of the large `2*136 x 2*136` matrix. So the diagonal are 2x2 matrices. Do the same for `L`. Then you can simply multiply both with each other, and the result (and especially the memory) can then be directly mapped back to the tensor. It does produce the same result, but it is only slightly faster than "EigenMapAndContract" and a factor of 30 slower than "DirectAccessWithOMP". Sorry, out of ideas.

Comment: In other words, I guess to achieve what you want you have to copy & paste the implementation of `contract()` and adapt it to your needs. From a quick look it seems like a non-trivial task. Also note, there is an existing [feature request](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/1907).

Comment: Sadly the PRs have not seen any action for a while.

Comment: For much much larger tensors like [2000, 2, 100, 2] x [2000, 2, 100, 2] (looping through the 0th and 2nd dims), the chip/slice loop is on par with the for loop using simd collapse(4). With omp parallel for num_threads(2) the for loop is just a bit above 2x faster. This is on the M2 chip with clang.

Comment: With omp parallel for on the for-loop and the slice/chip method, both are on par.

Answer (score 0):

### Minimum Working Example

Here's a working example. See [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:32,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:32,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3CEigen/Dense%3E%0A%23include+%3Cunsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor%3E%0A%0A/*%0AWant+to+mimic+the+following+from+Python:%0A%0Aimport+numpy+as+np%0AL+%3D+np.random.rand(2,+2,+136)%0AU+%3D+np.random.rand(2,+2,+136)%0Aresult+%3D+np.einsum(!%27ijl,jkl-%3Eikl!%27,+U,+L)%0A%0A*/%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++//+Setup+tensors%0A++++Eigen::Tensor%3Cdouble,+3%3E+U(2,+2,+136)%3B%0A++++Eigen::Tensor%3Cdouble,+3%3E+L(2,+2,+136)%3B%0A%0A++++//+Fill+with+random+vars%0A++++U.setRandom()%3B%0A++++L.setRandom()%3B%0A%0A++++//+Create+a+vector+of+dimension+pairs+you+want+to+contract+over%0A++++//+Since+j+is+the+second+index+in+the+second+tensor+(U)+we+specify+index+1,+since+j+is%0A++++//+the+first+index+for+the+second+tensor+(L),+we+specify+index+0.%0A++++Eigen::array%3CEigen::IndexPair%3Cint%3E,+1%3E+contraction_dims+%3D+%7BEigen::IndexPair%3Cint%3E(1,0)%7D%3B%0A%0A++++//+Perform+contraction+and+save+result%0A++++Eigen::Tensor%3Cdouble,+3%3E+result+%3D+U.contract(L,+contraction_dims)%3B%0A%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:eigen,ver:trunk)),options:%27-O3+-fopt-info-vec-missed%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+14.0.0%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) to run the code.

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>

int main() {
    // Setup tensors
    Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> U(2, 2, 136);
    Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> L(2, 2, 136);

    // Fill with random vars
    U.setRandom();
    L.setRandom();

    // Create a vector of dimension pairs you want to contract over
    // Since j is the second index in the second tensor (U) we specify index 1, since j is
    // the first index for the second tensor (L), we specify index 0.
    Eigen::array<Eigen::IndexPair<int>, 1> contraction_dims = {Eigen::IndexPair<int>(1,0)};

    // Perform contraction and save result
    Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> result = U.contract(L, contraction_dims);

}
```

### Vectorization

Vectorization is a tricky thing. You'll likely want to compile the code with `-O3 -fopt-info-vec-missed`, where `-fopt-info-vec-missed` will print out **very** detailed information about what vectorizations were missed. If you really really want further information about why your compiler is/isn't optimizing things the way you hoped, checkout tools like [`optview2`](https://github.com/OfekShilon/optview2) and [this great talk from CPPCON by Ofek Shilon](https://youtu.be/qmEsx4MbKoc). Hope this helps.

Comment: This isn't the correct contraction.